# How to set default post editor based on role?

Tags: functions, user-roles, editor

I found this code to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "html";') );
```

but I need to limit it to a specific set of roles (such as Editor or Author).

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_function()` is deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0, so you should avoid using it. Instead, use an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Additionally, it's better the check the current user role *inside* the callback function, so that the current user role is checked when the filter is applied, not when the hook is added, which could be before the current user role can be determined.

```
add_filter(
    'wp_default_editor',
    function( $default_editor ) {
        if ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) || current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
            $default_editor = 'html';
        }

        return $default_editor;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
if ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) || current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function( '', 'return "html";' ) );
}
```

Basically what you're doing is asking if the current user is an *editor* or an *author* before you add the filter.

As you mentioned, you essentially put this code into your *functions.php* file.